# How to use the GitHub API from Bash?

Tags: json, bash, github, github-api

I have a repo that I'm writing an 'installation script' in Bash for. My plan is to have all of the scripts I want to install in a `scripts/` directory under the repo root, and an script named `install` at the very top.

My plan is to have the user run something like this:

```
curl -sSL http://github.com/me/repo/raw/master/install | bash
```

and the install script will download all of the scripts in the directory on GitHub and place them in the appropriate place.

My question, how exactly would I do this from Bash? GitHub returns its API responses in JSON for example, so how would I parse the response contents in my script? Is there any way to change the response format so it would be Bash-parseable? (Bonus points if you provide a clear example for my specific use case.)

Thanks.

Comment: I've created a [repo](https://github.com/MarounMaroun/github-bash-api) for working with the GitHub API in Bash. It might be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have to use the Github API for this. You can instruct the user to get the raw file:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/repo/master/install | bash
```

This is a [common idiom](https://github.com/search?q=%22curl%20-sSL%20https%3A%2F%2Fraw.github.com%22&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93), apparently.

---

As an aside, I prefer using process substitution:

```
bash <(curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/repo/master/install)
```

This leaves the standard input unharmed, if you wish to use it.

---

If I misunderstood, and you intend to use the API for getting the list of scripts, it will be multi-step process:

1. Get the branch's tree from `https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/branches/master` from the `url` attribute.
2. The look up the directory in the entries of that tree (`https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/git/trees/hash`) - look for entities of type `tree`, `path` being `scripts`.
3. Then look for entries of type `blob` in *that* tree (`https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/git/trees/hash`)
4. Get each of those blobs, (`https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/git/blobs/hash`) and then `base64`-decode the `content` attribute (the encoding is also specified in the `encoding` attribute, so there's that to be handled as well).

It would be far, far easier to just maintain a list of scripts in your `scripts` directory, fetch that using a `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/repo/master/scripts/list-of-scripts` and then `curl` them. You could then do, for example:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/repo/master/scripts/list-of-scripts |
  xargs -L1 -i{} curl -sSL https://raw.github.com/me/repo/master/scripts/{}
```

---

If you really *must* use the API, the simplest way would be to use [the `jq` tool](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/). Download it in your script (change version, OS and architecture as needed):

```
curl -sSL https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.5/jq-linux64 > jq
chmod +x jq
```

Now begins the long torturous journey:

```
tree_url=$(curl -sSL https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/branches/master | 
  ./jq -r '.commit.commit.tree.url')
script_tree=$(curl -sSL "$tree_url" | 
  ./jq -r '.tree[] | select(.type == "tree" and .path == "scripts") | .url')
curl -sSL "$script_tree" | 
  ./jq -r '.tree[] | select(.type == "blob") | .url' | 
   xargs curl -sSLO
```

And now run `base64 -d` on each of the newly downloaded files (you could use a loop instead of `xargs` to make it easier).

Alternatively, for that last step, you could do:

```
curl -sSL "$script_tree" | 
  ./jq -r '.tree[] | select(.type == "blob") | .path' |
  xargs -L1 -i{} curl -sSLO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/repo/master/scripts/{}
```

Comment: I initially downvoted your question, but your second edit corrects it. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: Even better, thanks. I hadn't known about jq before this. Superb answer!